# live search in Google sheet with inline editing

Tags: google-sheets, search, spreadsheet

Any workaround or extension to make google sheet filter row **as you type**?

I know about query and filter but these don't allow inline editing.
if its not posible in google sheet, is there any npm package to do similar thing which has spreadsheet+live search in it.

[image: something like editor in datatables]

Comment: You seem to be asking about filtering an html table, not a Google sheet? At least, your image is not a sheet

Comment: its not,i posted this to point out the feature I am looking for in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Okay, well, npm scripts cannot inject functionality into your browser, so I'm not sure I understand the question, but yeah, you can build your own webpage with live html table filtering

Comment: in case its not possible in google sheet, I wanted simple ready to go npm package that will give me sheet like interface ,ready to copy paste,and use spreadsheet like functionality in local environment, surprising that I haven't found anything like this, this is so much needed imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative with live search spreadsheet
its Handsontable package works with javascript and other frameworks.